# How can I use a json value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

I want to use the ID of an image in jQuery.

I am loading the ID in html with json:

```
<script type="text/template" id="assets-template">
{{#assets}}
   <li>
     <div id = "assetId">{{id}}</div>
   </li>
{{/assets}}
</script>
```

When I try:

```
var postId = document.getElementById("assetId").text;
```

It says undefined...

Thanks!

Comment: where is your json file

Comment: you should try after the dom is loaded fully. i.e. post the above script initialization

Comment: My JSON file is at a database server. The ID is displayed on the page. But I can't get it with jquery it says undefined

Comment: try .innerHTML instead of .text

Comment: Thanks @FranePoljak ! Although it loads the id as a number. It is the same for my whole list. How can I change it so it will load the id for the coresponding <li> ?

Answer (score 0):

You should make your Javascript being triggered by `jQuery(document).ready()`. This way Javascript will be executed when the full page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code
    var postId = $("#assetId").text();
    // more of your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading json data from ajax call then keep this at on sucess`var postId = document.getElementById("assetId").text;`.If you are loading on page load write it after your `DOM`  is initialized.